# Global variables in ASP.NET as static fields and properties no locking required?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, global-variables

Here is an article about the subject [global-variables-aspnet](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variables-aspnet)

In a given example on page load there is an initialization of our static global variable:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // 1.
    // Get the current ImportantData.
    string important1 = Global.ImportantData;

    // 2.
    // If we don't have the data yet, initialize it.
    if (important1 == null)
    {
        // Example code.
        important1 = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        Global.ImportantData = important1;
    }

    // 3.
    // Render the important data.
    Important1.Text = important1;
}
```

And the commentary to it:

> Performance: Static fields are efficient in normal situations. You
>   will only have one copy of the data and there is no locking required.

My question is - why there is no double-null-check and no locking required?
Am I missing something is ASP.NET multi-threading?

Comment: I will say that framework does that for you. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the article is incorrect, at least when considering the generalized statement: No locking required, ever. I am not aware of any mechanism that would automatically serialize access to static members in the Global class, and I am also not aware of any ASP.Net mechanism that would serialize Page_Load calls. While that article only showed read access after a one-time initialization (in most cases, see end of post), it stands to reason that somebody will be mislead by it and use those static members to read and write at different times. Example:

```
public static class Global
{
    public static int PageRequests;
}

...

protected void Page_Load()
{
    // This construct without locking might lead to lost counts
    Global.PageRequests++;
}
```

Locking is definitely required here, unless you don't care if your page request count is not entirely accurate.

In the specific case with the DateTime initialization and read-only access afterwards, you can live without a lock. Should two Page_Load threads successfully test for important1 == null at around the same time, they would both write the same or almost same DateTime value into that variable, and from a split second later on, this variable will never be changed again because important1 == null will then evaluate to false. But this is a very special case where it doesn't matter. Certainly not a generalization.

Comment: I'm very sorry. Totally forgot to accept the answer )